# Mongoose Find Method Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, mongoose-schema

I just started to learn mongoose. I used the `find()` method to fetch all the tour data from the database.
When I don't pass anything to the `find()` method, it shows all of the results, which is correct. However, when I try to filter all the documents and I pass the *wrong* object into `find()` method, that *also* shows all the tour results.

1. List item

my **TourSchema**

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");


const tourSchema=new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        unique:true
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        require:[true,"A tour must have price"],
    },
    ratingsAverage:{
        type:Number
    },
    ratingQuantity:{
        type:Number,
    },
    duration:{
           type:Number

    },
    ratingsAverage:{
        type:Number,
        default:4,
        min:1,
        max:5
    },
    difficulty:{
        type:String,
        enum:["easy","medium","difficult"]
    },
    maxGroupSize:{
        type:Number,
        require:[true,"A tour must have group size"],
 },
 description:{
    type:String,
    trim:true,
    require:[true,'A tour must have description']
 },
 imageCover:{
    type:String,
    require:[true,'A tour must have imageCover']
 },
 images:[String],
 startDates:{
    type:[Date]
 },
 summary:{
type:String,
trim:true,
require:[true,"A tour must have summary"]
 }



})

const Tour=new model('Tour',tourSchema);

module.exports=Tour;
```

**findAllTour.js**

```
exports.getAllTour =async(req, res) => {
try{
    // console.log(req.query)
    const tours=await Tour.find({"sjfa":5});
    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        results: tours.length,
        data: {
            tours
        },
    })
}
```

I pass wrong field in find method,  its work fine, means show all the tour

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GeGt.png)

Comment: If I understand you correctly your expected result is that `Tour.find({"sjfa":5})` returns an empty array and currently it is showing all documents from this collection, correct? I was not able to reproduce this issue. When I filter for criteria not contained in the schema, I get an empty result set, which is the desired behaviour.

Comment: yes,can you explain why this show all tours instead of empty tour or error

Comment: can you please also paste what exactly your response is? The only option I see is that the returned documents have this attribute "sjfa", even if it's not contained in the schema.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior since mongoose `6.0.10` which makes `strictQuery` equal to `strict` by default, filtering out properties that are not in the schema.

If you need to disable `strictQuery` you can either set:

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
```

Or run:

```
const tours = await Tour.find({ "sjfa":5 }, null, { strictQuery: false });
```

For more information, check the official [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#strictquery-is-removed-and-replaced-by-strict) or [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10763) discussion.